# ContentResolver gives me wrong content uri

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, kotlin-coroutines, android-glide

**Context :**

In my app I use the `ContentResolver` to get images from content uri :

```kotlin
val collectionArrayTmp = arrayListOf<PhotoCollection>()

val mediaStoreUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
val projection = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE
)

contentResolver?.query(mediaStoreUri, projection, null, null, null)?.use {

    val folderIdColumnIndex by lazy { it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID) }
    val folderNameColumnIndex by lazy { it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME) }
    val idColumnIndex by lazy { it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID) }
    val dateColumnIndex by lazy { it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN) }
    val nameColumnIndex by lazy { it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE) }

    while (it.moveToNext()) {

        val folderId = it.getString(folderIdColumnIndex)
        var folderName = it.getString(folderNameColumnIndex)
        val id = it.getString(idColumnIndex)
        val width = it.getInt(widthColumnIndex)
        val height = it.getInt(heightColumnIndex)
        val date = Date(it.getLong(dateColumnIndex))
        val name = it.getString(nameColumnIndex)
        val path = Uri.withAppendedPath(mediaStoreUri, ""+id)

        // If folderName is null, get parent folder name
        if (folderName == null) {

            val splitedPath = path.toString().split("/")
            folderName = splitedPath[splitedPath.lastIndex - 1]

        }

        val photo = Photo(
            uri = path,
            originalId = id,
            date = date,
            name = name,
        )

        // If asset PhotoCollection already exists just add it
        // Else create new PhotoCollection
        collectionArrayTmp.find { collection -> collection.id == folderId }?.apply {

            photoArray.add(photo)

        } ?: run {

            val photoCollection = PhotoCollection(
                id = folderId,
                name = folderName,
                photoArray = arrayListOf(photo)
            )

            collectionArrayTmp.add(photoCollection)

        }

    }

}
```

**Issue :**

The issue is that sometimes, the query gives me some invalid results : I get uri path, size, name...etc, but when I want to call these Uris, through Glide in my case, I get an error like "File not found". These case is very rare but possible, so I search how to solve it.

For information, in the Google's file app, it seems the issue is here too : I see a photo file, but when I want to open that photo in a gallery I get an error

**Temporary solution :**

For now, my solution is to check all images to see if the Uri is correct

```kotlin
data class PhotoCollection(
    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var photoArray: ArrayList<Photo> = arrayListOf()
)

data class Photo(
    var uri: Uri? = null
    var date: Date = Date(0)
    var id: String = ""
    var name: String? = null
)

private suspend fun cleanOrphanPhotos(collectionArray: ArrayList<PhotoCollection>) = coroutineScope {

    for (collection in collectionArray) {

       synchronized(collection) {

           launch {

               for (photo in collection.photoArray) {

                   launch {

                       photo.uri?.let { uri ->

                           val exists = uri.localImageExists()
                           if (!exists)
                               collection.photoArray.remove(photo)

                       }

                   }

               }

           }

       }

    }

}

fun Uri.localImageExists() : Boolean {

    try {

        GlideApp.with(App.context)
            .asDrawable()
            .timeout(400)
            .override(10 , 10)
            .load(this)
            .submit()
            .get()

        return true

    } catch (e: Exception) {

        return false

    }

}
```

I'm using `coroutines` to check all images at the same time, but for a lot of images it's quite slow (~30sec for 2000+ images).

Anyone get a solution to avoid theses images or to check images faster ?
Thanks a lot for your help, have a nice day

Comment: It would be great if you can post what query you are setting for the `ContentResolver` instance to use. Also as a suggestion please try debugging the query by logging it

Comment: @gtxtreme thanks for your answer, I've added more code for the ```ContentResolver```

Comment: `ContentResolver gives me wrong content uri` Is the uri wrong or has the file behind it meanwhile been deleted?

Comment: `in the Google's file app, it seems the issue is here too : I see a photo file, but when I want to open that photo in a gallery I get an error` Well then i will not blame your app. Leave it as it is. It will encourage the user to clean up the phone.

Comment: @blackapps I think the file is deleted, but the ```ContentResolver``` still finds an Uri

Comment: Yes, such things happen. And you can easily check if that is the case. Why worry about deleted files? The contentresolver does not find them. Wrong talking. They are still in the database of the mediastore. Thats all. Check if they are deleted. Find out. Then reboot device.